# Knockout view model overriding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I will try to explain it as short as possible.
I have a single-page application that is using knockout.js to bind my `viewModel` data to the HTML.
The problem arises when I use AJAX to deliver new HTML and new `data`.

The HTML gets placed properly onto the page, and the data-binding works as intended, no error there. However, the view model doesn't get overridden, instead, new elements get added to it. For example:

```
//initial viewModel before AJAX call:
var viewModel = {
  someData: "dataFromInitialPage",
  secondData: "someMoreDataFromInitialPage"
}

//viewModel after AJAX call:
var viewModel = {
  someData: "dataFromInitialPage",
  secondData: "someMoreDataFromInitialPage"
  thirdData: "thisDataIsFromAJAX"
}
```

Now I am using `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, model);` to update the model, and I understand why this is happening (or I think I do, the model is trying to update itself based on the new data). But what I need is to make the model FORGET it had the initial data and make a whole new set of data on the same **variable**. I do not know why does it insist on keeping the old information that is no longer used in the new HTML content page.

Note: the variable is actually not a standalone variable, it is a property of an object, like so:

```
var webApp = {
  viewModel: (this variable here),
  //some other properties are present here as well
}
```

Comment: The `mapping.fromJS` signature is: `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, viewModelToMapTo)`. The default options probably only extend and do not delete missing properties. I made a mistake in my answer and had no time to fix it, so I deleted it. Hope this still helps you a bit...

Comment: It does, I added methods to create a new object every time an update is ran, then assign the model's property to the new object, that way, regardless of it is new or update, it will only have the data set that is the newest received one.